# Adding Meta Tags to Menu Link Blocks

Tags: blocks

I have successfully added Meta Tags to the front page of my Drupal 7 site and to pages. However I can't seem to add meta tags to blocks? How do I do this?

Comment: Given that meta tags are only valid in the `<head>` of an HTML document, what do you mean by "add meta tags to blocks"?